# Special syntax for declaring Ruby objects

Tags: ruby, object

Everyone knows two of the ways to create an empty array: `Array.new` and `[]`. The first one is 'standard', you might say, and the second one is simply syntax sugar. Many different objects such as `Hash` and maybe even `String` are shorthanded through this method.

My question is: Is there a way to define my own delimimers for objects? An example would be `<>`. Maybe an alias like `'<' => 'MyObject.new('` and `'>' => ')'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` is an **array literal**, `{}` is a **hash literal**. There are plenty of these shorthand forms in Ruby. Check [this wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals) out for more information.

There is no object literal, but you can use ([source](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/8b8edc25bdb6b60f)):

```
a = Struct.new(:foo,:bar).new(34,89)
a.foo # 34
a.bar # 89
```

Answer (score 1):

No. *(And ew anyway.)* Delimiters are part of the parse process.

You can define operators, like `<`; that's different than a delimiter. For example, you could redefine `<` to take a block, and use that block to create a class, or a method, etc. But... I don't think I would.

Comment: Aww... I was hoping for something like the C/C++ preproccesor :)

Comment: @itdoesntwork Then use a pre-processor, but I think you're barking up a tree that's liable to fall on you and crush you without mercy.

Comment: Well, I wasn't planning on doing that; it was hypothetical. I can imagine some problems that it might cause.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
class MyObject; end

def [](*args)
  MyObject.new *args
end

# but you can't use it directly:
o = []       #=> [] (empty Array)

# you must to refer to self:
o = self[]   #=> #<MyObject:0x1234567>

# but since self depends on where are you, you must assign self to a global variable:
$s = self
o = $s[]

# or to a constant:
S = self
o = S[]

# however, in that case it's better to do it in the proper class:
class << MyObject
  def [](*args)
    new *args
  end
end

# and assign it to a single-letter constant to reduce characters:
S = MyObject

# so
o = S[]    #=> #<MyObject:0x1234568>
```

I can't think on something more compact.

Comment: The goal here wasn't to discover the most minimalistic way to define an object. I just wanted to see if defining literals was possible.